# Execute a XQuery with PHP

Tags: php, xquery

How to execute a [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) in [PHP](http://php.net)? Can you give me an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

pear package: http://www.pecl.php.net/package/Zorba  (error 404 link)

NEW (2011): http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2011/12/27/PHP_Meets_XQuery

zorba documentation: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/

zorba docs provide a simple example:

```
//Include for the Object-Oriented API
require ‘zorba_api.php’;

//Initialization of Zorba store
$store = InMemoryStore::getInstance();
//Initialization of Zorba
$zorba = Zorba::getInstance($store);

$xquery = <<< EOT
let $message := ‘Hello World!’
return
<results>
   <message>{$message}</message>
</results>
EOT;

//Compile the query
$lQuery = $zorba->compileQuery($xquery);
//Run the query…
echo $lQuery->execute();
//…and destroy it
$lQuery->destroy();

//Shutdown of Zorba
$zorba->shutdown();
//Shutdown of Zorba store
InMemoryStore::shutdown($store);
```

Comment: Same comment as for Dominik (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211743/execute-a-xquery-with-php#comment-2163837). Really, nothing more simple?

Comment: [That package no longer exists in PECL](http://www.pecl.php.net/packages.php?catpid=22&catname=XML)

Answer (score 6):

PHP does not have any native or common XML parsers that support XQuery (If I'm wrong, someone let me know). It does however have two pretty standard extensions that handle XPath queries.

I personally think `simplexml` is the better of the two. You would simply use:

```
$xml = new simplexml($some_xml_string);
$xpath_results = $xml -> Xpath("//a/b");
```

And then loop through the results.

The extensive DOM class supports Xpath queries as well. The only real advantage, as far as I see it, to using DOM is that the results can be modified or deleted straight out of the larger XML object.

Good luck.

Comment: XPath isn't the same as XQuery.

Comment: I know, right?  That's probably why the first thing I said was that PHP doesn't have native support for XQUERY.  I guess next time, I shouldn't add helpful alternative solutions.

Comment: I still don't think that for a question as generic as this one xpath is a viable alternative for xquery. At least it requires some big assumptions. But anyway....

Comment: Fair enough.  Basically pointing to XPath is really just to spare them the journey I've taken with PHP and XML, where I read about some XML standard technology, get excited, find out it's *kind of* supported in PHP, and even then not without recompiling. Happend with me for XQuery, XSLT, SOAP/WSDL, XPath, and I'm sure it will happen again.  Not hating on PHP, just saying XML will break hearts, with all of it's big promises.

Comment: On that I can full-heartedly agree. "XML is like violence. If it doesn't solve your problems you didn't use enough of it". On the one hand it's abused too often, on the other hand it's too often used with sub-par tools. And strangely enough both cases coincide way, way too often within the same project (or company). | And looking up the subsequent questions of abernier it seems as xpath did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use BaseX. Its stable, scaleable, and fast!
(but you need a server to run)

[BaseX clients](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Clients)

```
include("BaseXClient.php");

$session = new Session("localhost", 1984, "admin", "admin");
print $session->execute("xquery 1 to 10");
$session->close();
```

Answer (score 2):

its also posible with DOMDocument and DOMXPath

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://www.example.com/some.xml');
$xpd = new DOMXPath($doc);
false&&$node = new DOMElement();//this is for my IDE to have intellysense

$result = $xpd->query('//a/b');
foreach($result as $node){
    echo $node->nodeName.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this page at http://phpxmlclasses.sourceforge.net/ that has an XQuery Lite class:

- http://phpxmlclasses.sourceforge.net/show_doc.php?class=class_xquery_lite.html

> A PHP implementation of the Xquery Lite 1.0 language, a language to query XML documents based on Xquery 1.0 This class is based on the DOM extension and allows to execute Xquery Lite queries for XML documents in files, php strings or combinations.

I have never used it and do not know how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

The following link should be useful: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1487285/php/php.html

```
<?php
require_once 'Zorba/XQueryProcessor.php'; 

$xquery = new XQueryProcessor(); 

$query = <<<'XQ'
  declare variable $world external; 
  <h1>Hello {$world}</h1>
XQ; 

$xquery->importQuery($query); 

$xquery->setVariable('world', 'World!'); 

echo $xquery->execute(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For shared hosting scenarios, I suggest to use something like 28msec (http://www.28msec.com) which enables you to build RESTful services based on top of the Zorba XQuery processor.
From PHP you can connect to 28msec via REST.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have a look at http://www.pecl.php.net/package/Zorba ?

Comment: Dude! Compiling just for executing a simple query?! Sounds like rocket science here... nothing more simple?

Comment: [That package no longer exists in PECL](http://www.pecl.php.net/packages.php?catpid=22&catname=XML)