# SimpleXML get element content based on attribute value

Tags: php, css-selectors, simplexml

I'm trying to access the content of an element based on the value of an attribute. With PHP SimpleXML. I've got the following XML setup:

```
<DocSum> 
    <Id>21242919</Id> 
    <Item Name="Author" Type="String">Nguyen T</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">[Hemoptysis and spontaneous rupture of a primary renal angiosarcoma: a case report.]</Item>
</DocSum>
<DocSum> 
    <Id>21242919</Id> 
    <Item Name="Author" Type="String">Oliveira GC</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">Disclosing ambiguous gene aliases by automatic literature profiling.</Item>
</DocSum>
<DocSum> 
    <Id>21242919</Id> 
    <Item Name="Author" Type="String">Vanderwall DE</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">Metformin and digestive disorders.</Item>
</DocSum>
```

These are books. In this case I'm trying to get the title. What I have so far is this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(url);
$docs = $xml->DocSum;
foreach($docs as $book){
        // Each book individual
}
```

Where the comment is I tried a lot of things.

Comment: @Gordon: I think this is asking what to use, not how to use it.

Comment: @Alejandro quoting the OP in that question "I want to select the nodes based on the date" where date is an attribute of an element. Bob asks how to get the "content of an element based on the value of an attribute". There is no difference to me.

Comment: @Gordon: OP also wrote *"and I am using this XQuery and XPath to select the nodes"* and explicitly ask for XPath and XQuery in title.

Comment: @Alejandro the accepted solution is an XPath though and given that there is no [official XQuery support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211743/execute-a-xquery-with-php/2212356) in any of the native PHP XML extensions … :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) query on the SimpleXML object will return all `DocSum` nodes that have an `Item` child with value "Author" in the `Name` attribute and value "Olivera GC" in the text node:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//DocSum[Item[@Name="Author" and .="Oliveira GC"]]');
$book = $nodes[0];
print_r($book);
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, I suspect the solution will be [`XPATH`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)...

If you're trying to get the title of a book by the id, you'd use the query:

```
$query = '//DocSum/Id[contains(., "21232919")]';
```

If you're trying to search for the title of a book:

```
$query = '//DocSum/Item[@Name="Title" AND contains(., "Metformin")]';
```

Then just run it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$results = $xml->xpath($query);
foreach ($results as $titleElement) {
    $book = simplexml_import_dom(dom_import_simplexml($titleElement)->parentNode);
    // Handle the book here
}
```

I'm converting back and forth between simplexml and domdocument since that appears to be the only documented way of traversing up the tree...

Comment: Actually, XPath is supported out of the box in SimpleXML, so you don't actually have to convert to DOM or create a DomXpath object. See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Thanks @Josh, I've edited it in (but I still need the conversion to access the parent)

Comment: You can select the parents just with XPath. Check [@scoffey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736417/simplexml-get-element-content-based-on-attribute-value/4736714#4736714)'s answer.