# simpleXML get node child based on attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse out the value of a node I am referencing by one of its attributes. but I am not sure of the syntax

XML:

```
<data>

  <poster name="E-Verify" id="everify">

    <full_image url="e-verify-swa-poster.jpg"/>

    <full_other url=""/>

  </poster>


  <poster name="Minimum Wage" id="minwage">

    <full_image url="minwage.jpg"/>

    <full_other url="spa_minwage.jpg"/>

  </poster>
</data>
```

here is where I want to get the url value of full_image where poster id equal to minwage:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('PosterData.xml');
$main_url = $xml->full_image[name] where poster[id] = "minwage";
//something like that.
echo $main_url;

Result: minwage.jpg
```

If anyone has any resources that cover this stuff please share.

Comment: As you asked for resources, yes there is: [Implementing condition in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448005/implementing-condition-in-xpath) and [SimpleXML get element content based on attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4736417/367456)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply loop the poster elements and remember to cast the attribute values to strings, since you want to compare them (and probably output them) as strings:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('PosterData.xml');

foreach ($xml->poster as $poster) {
    if ((string) $poster['id'] == 'minwage') {
        echo (string) $poster->full_image['url'];
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. I was def over thinking the process. +1

Answer (score 30):

You should be able to use [SimpleXMLElement::xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to run an [xpath query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) on a simple XML document.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('PosterData.xml');
$main_url = $xml->xpath('name[@id="minwage"]/full_image')[0];

echo $main_url;
```

Comment: This is how I was trying originally. thanks for the info.

Comment: This is a lot more elegant than just looping and should be the excepted answer.

Comment: I've been trying to make this code work, by duplicating the code on my localhost, yet I get "Undefined Offset: 0"  Please see:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154956/xpath-query-on-simplexml-document-undefined-offset-0

Comment: Shouldn't "name" in 'name[@id="minwage"]' be "poster"? Since the element is a "poster" element?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$object = simplexml_load_string('<data><poster name="E-Verify" id="everify"><full_image url="e-verify-swa-poster.jpg"/><full_other url=""/></poster><poster name="Minimum Wage" id="minwage"><full_image url="minwage.jpg"/><full_other url="spa_minwage.jpg"/></poster></data>');

foreach ($object as $value) {
    echo "URL: ".$value->full_image->attributes();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Either use `simplexml_load_file('Some external file.xml')` if calling external file.