# xpath query on SimpleXML Document - Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm quite new to SimpleXML and using xpath within it. I wasn't sure whether to post this query within the original posting or here, so I linked to here form the original posting.

In working through several test scripts, I came across this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696545/simplexml-get-node-child-based-on-attribute), and I've been attempting to make one of the accepted answers work.
However, when I attempt to use the xpath version of the accepted answer work, I get the error message:

```
Undefined offset: 0
```

I've tested xpath in other ways, to verify that it is installed and functional.  Thanks for any leads.

I have duplicated the OP's xml file, along with the accepted answer code:

XML:

```
<data>
  <poster name="E-Verify" id="everify">
    <full_image url="e-verify-swa-poster.jpg"/>
    <full_other url=""/>
  </poster>
  <poster name="Minimum Wage" id="minwage">
    <full_image url="minwage.jpg"/>
    <full_other url="spa_minwage.jpg"/>
  </poster>
</data>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$url = "test_b.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$main_url = $xml->xpath('name[@id="minwage"]/full_image')[0];
?>
```

Comment: Your xpath expression is looking for an element called `<name>`, which doesn't exist. Do you mean `poster`?

Comment: I copied it from the op here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696545/simplexml-get-node-child-based-on-attribute
I had thought the same - in my tests, using 'poster' in xpath worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath was looking for a non-existant element called `name` and not finding it.  This will mean there isn't a 0 element to fetch using the `[0]`.   I've changed the element name to `poster` and in this example I fetch the `url` attribute, but you can change it to whatever else you need...

```
$main_url = $xml->xpath('//poster[@id="minwage"]/full_image/@url')[0];
echo $main_url;
```

gives...

```
minwage.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks - it's good to know that I was almost there.  Does the [0] specify an array level within the @url variable?

Comment: When you use `xpath` it will return an array of matching elements.  So it's just a case of `[0]` will be the first match.

Comment: One more question ... why can't url be put in brackets, instead of after the forward slash, like was done with id and poster?  e.g. xpath('//poster[id="minwage"]/full_image[url]')[0]
In the xml, it looks like url is an attribute, just like id is.  I tried it, but it does not work, but I'm unsure why.  Thanks.  (note: I had to remove the @ signs, due to confusion with users, here).

Comment: Square brackets in an XPath expression are slightly different, if you used `//full_image[@url]` this would mean to find any full_image which has a url attribute.  Whereas `//full_image[url]` mean to find a full_image element which has a url element inside it.   So [] is used as a condition in XPath and for arrays in PHP.