# How to get the xml sub-parameters

Tags: php, xml, get

How to get the xml sub-parameters?
how to get all the results of `category` and return a result `$category` .. `category = Test1, Test2`

my xml

```
<xml>
<title>Test 123</title>
<categories>
<category>Test1</category>
<category>Test2</category>
</categories>
</xml>
```

my get code

```
$category = htmlspecialchars($item->categories->category, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo $category; //I want to return Test1, Test2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access all children of a certain node with simplexml and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054386/access-all-children-of-a-certain-node-with-simplexml-and-php)

Comment: No!  i want to take all the subparimetres of `categories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop `$item->categories->category` using a `foreach`:

```
$source = <<<DATA
<xml>
<title>Test 123</title>
<categories>
<category>Test1</category>
<category>Test2</category>
</categories>
</xml>
DATA;

$item = simplexml_load_string($source);

foreach ($item->categories->category as $elm) {
    echo $elm . PHP_EOL;
}
```

That will give you:

```
Test1
Test2
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/hBvlc)

Comment: Hello, man I get information with `simplexml_load_file` and this script does not work with it.. Help ?

Comment: @I.Nikolaew Can you add the script that you use  to load the file to the question? Does the xml look exactly like that? I tested it like this `$item = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");` and it seems to work.

Comment: My php code is
```$xml     = simplexml_load_file($rss_url);
foreach ($xml->offert as $item) {
    foreach ($item->categories->category as $category) {
    $category      = htmlspecialchars($category, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').',';
....```

*<offert>

<categories>
<category>Test1</category>
<category>Test2</category>
</categories>...</offert>*

Comment: @I.Nikolaew Instead of using `$xml->offert` you could use `$xml->categories->category` see https://3v4l.org/IVK1g or if you have multipe see https://3v4l.org/UK23I

Comment: Here is my code: https://3v4l.org/48Ue7 as I try to do it and it does not work ..

Comment: @I.Nikolaew I have made some minor changes to the code, it should work now https://3v4l.org/agnHX

Comment: Not working see Output .. must return  `Name = Title-1 || Category = Test1,Test2` not that 
`Name = Title-1 || Category = Test1
Name = Title-1 || Category = Test2`

Comment: @I.Nikolaew I see what you mean, then you could use https://3v4l.org/R5gMc

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what are you searching for?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<item id="1234">
<property name="country_id">
    <value>4402</value>
</property>
<property name="rc_maintenance_other">
</property>
<property name="claim_right_shareholder">
</property>
<property name="charges_other">
</property>
<property name="other_expenses_heating">
</property>
<property name="unpaid_bills_amount">
</property>
<property name="iv_person_phone">
    <value>03-6756711</value>
</property>
</item>
 ');

foreach ($xml->xpath('//item[@id="1234"]') as $item)
{    
    foreach ($item->children() as $child) {
      echo $child['name'] ."\n";
    }
}
```

duplicate question?
[Access all children of a certain node with simplexml and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054386/access-all-children-of-a-certain-node-with-simplexml-and-php)