# SimpleXML show data from a particular atribute

Tags: xml, simplexml

I'm a total noob and I have a question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. To output the clicks from item with promocode selma fro the example below. I can use

```
 $data=simplexml_load_file("data.xml"); 

 echo $data->item[1]->clicks.'<br />';
```

But can someone please show me the code how to output the clicks using the attribute name. Something like

```
 echo $data->item[selma]->clicks.'<br />';
```

I know this is wrong but I hope you get my question. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<data>
 <item promocode="harry" program="250" program_name="PPS Web">
  <clicks>3730</clicks>
  <PPSWeb30>0</PPSWeb30>
  <PPSWeb75>17</PPSWeb75>
  <total>1275</total>
</item>
<item promocode="selma" program="251" program_name="PPS Mobile">
 <clicks>366</clicks>
 <PPSWeb30>0</PPSWeb30>
 <PPSWeb75>1</PPSWeb75>
 <total>75</total>
</item>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using XPATH

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//item[@promocode="selma"]');

$item = $nodes[0];
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736417/simplexml-get-element-content-based-on-attribute-value)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want. You have to go through each item's attributes and compare and get the clicks.

```
$xml = '<data>
        <item promocode="harry" program="250" program_name="PPS Web">
          <clicks>3730</clicks>
          <PPSWeb30>0</PPSWeb30>
          <PPSWeb75>17</PPSWeb75>
          <total>1275</total>
        </item>
        <item promocode="selma" program="251" program_name="PPS Mobile">
         <clicks>366</clicks>
         <PPSWeb30>0</PPSWeb30>
         <PPSWeb75>1</PPSWeb75>
         <total>75</total>
        </item>
    </data>';

$data = simplexml_load_string($xml); 

$search_promo = "selma";

foreach ($data->item as $item) {
    $attributes = $item->attributes();
    if ($attributes["promocode"] == $search_promo) {
        $clicks = $item->clicks; // 366
        //...
    }
}
```