# Evaluate XPath 2.0 in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am currently working on a project written in PHP and want to evaluate XPath expression on XML files. Since the files are a quite complex, my XPath contains expressions like *for...in...return*-loops or other features introduced with XPath 2. Unfortunately PHP's [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class supports only XPath 1.0, and I didn't find any XPath 2.0 evaluator for PHP.  Has anybody faced the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: It's actually [libxml2 which doesn't support it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205580/why-doesnt-libxml2-support-xpath-2-0). There are a few [XQuery implementations for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211743/execute-a-xquery-with-php) though. Else you'll have to rewrite it for one of the fluent DOM frontends perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

[Saxon/C](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) (currently in beta) can be called from PHP.  It's open source, covered under the Mozilla Public License 2.0.  Linux, Windows and Mac OS X are supported.

Alternatively, in lieu of support for XPath 2.0 you could just re-write your XPaths to use XPath 1.0 proper and cover iteration etc outside of XPath in PHP itself.