# XPath find if an attributes value is in a array list

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, domxpath

I would like to select with xpatch all `<a>` tags that have the href attribute equal to a value present in an array with a list of urls.

Although I have found many examples on stackoverflow all of them return me this error: `<b> Warning </b>: DOMXPath :: query (): Invalid expression in...`

this is the code i tested without success:

```
$xpath->query("//a[@href=('facebook.com', 'google.com', 'amazon.com')]");
```

if try with one value work correctly, like this:

```
$xpath->query("//a[@href=('facebook.com')]");
```

but if i try to add a multi-value return the error mentioned, i have an array with around 1000 URL and i want select all link that have the href attributes value present in my array.

this is the code for load with xpatch the DOM loaded with DOMDocument

```
$dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
         
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
```

**I would like to clarify that speed of execution is important to me.
In your opinion, is it faster to select all the links and then make a check outsite xpatch through a foreach loop with in_array or is it faster to insert the condition directly into xpatch ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025885/xpath-1-0-to-find-if-an-elements-value-is-in-a-list-of-values shows how to do this in 1 XPath expression, but with so many URL's, you may be better off retrieving all the href values and then and checking them in a loop.

Comment: I have already seen the page you indicated and my example is the same as the answer concerning xpatch 2.0, you refer to which example.
I would like to point out that execution speed is important to me, so do you think a separate loop is faster or slower than a condition directly with xpatch?

Answer (score 0):

Testing against a list of values requires XPath 2.0, but the PHP [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) library [only supports XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28142859/290085).  Therefore, you cannot use

```
//a[@href=('facebook.com', 'google.com', 'amazon.com')]
```

Instead, use

```
//a[@href='facebook.com' or @href='google.com' or @href='amazon.com']
```

As to execution speed relative to other alternatives, such as using XPath to acquire all `a` elements and iterating in the hosting language to filter those of interest, follow the universal rule of performance evaluation: ***Measure**, don't guess* (or ask others to guess for you).