Find Version of XPath in Simple XML for PHP
I am working in PHP and using SimpleXML and XPath.
Is there a way to find which version of XPath is included with SimpleXML/PHP?
Also, is the version of XPath used with SimpleXML the "full version" with all of the features as a "non-SimpleXML" version (in particular "fn:sort")?
Thanks for input and leads.

PHP does not support XPath 2.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142859/evaluate-xpath-2-0-in-php

Generally, if the documentation just says "XPath" then it's a reasonable assumption that it's XPath 1.0, because both the software and documentation were written when that was the only version in town. But it's easy to check, e.g. by trying a function like current-date(). If you want a later version, you'll need a third-party library such as (my company's product) SaxonC.

As stated in the docs, SimpleXML requires libxml

This extension requires the libxml PHP extension

and according to libxml homepage, XPATH 1.0 is the implemented version

XML Path Language (XPath) 1.0: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath

